# Sum of rows and groupby using eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Having the following columns:

```
category, rating, num_users, date_voted /*number of users*/
```

How do I get the rating grouped by category as the sum of the number of users over a given range of dates using eloquent

```
Category::groupBy('num_users') //returns the categories
```

Example of the Main table data

```
--------------------------------
category| rating| num_users| date_voted
---------------------------------------
Action  |5      |2         | 12-12-2015
Comedy  |2      |2         | 12-12-2015
Fantasy |3      |2         | 12-12-2015
Action  |4      |2         | 14-12-2015
Comedy  |5      |2         | 14-12-2015
```

I want the html table to be in the form of category vs ratings(between 1 and 5) eg

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Category|Rating 1|Rating 2|Rating 3|Rating 4|Rating 5|
------------------------------------------------------
Action  |2       |3       |5       |5       |9       |  
Comedy  |9       |8       |6       |9       |14      | 
Fantasy |1       |2       |3       |6       |7       |
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want get sum of num users group by category you can use:

```
Category::groupBy('category')
->selectRaw('sum(num_users) as num_users , category')
->get();
```

Comment: hi Gouda Elalfy, I've expressed my problem more with an edit

Comment: @TimothyRadier can you provide some main table data

Answer (score 1):

May be it will help you

```
Category::select(DB::raw('sum(users) as total_users'),'category')->groupBy('category')->get();
```

Comment: hi Imtiaz Pabel, I've expressed my problem more with an edit